# Query for exact match of a string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query for the exact match of a string from a database table.

When I write the query as

```
select description from tproduct where description like '%diamond%'
```

it runs and gives the results as a `wild card` query. For example, I got ringdiamond, diamondmaster, etc.

But I want to get only "diamond".

For this I did as:

```
select description from tproduct where description = 'diamond'
```

But it is giving an error:

> Error: Unknown column 'diamond' in 'where clause'

The description column contains:

```
This bracelet is composed of round diamond surrounded by milgrain detailing. Its secure setting prevents it from twisting and ensures it will sit impeccably on her wrist.


This stylish design is the perfect accessory for the day or evening. Akoya cultured pearls are lined up by a string of bezel-set round diamond.
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use double quotes by accident?

Comment: @John Gibb: Yeah, i am very sure. i used only single quotes

Comment: If you want to use `LIKE`, just use it without the wildcard entries, `select description from tproduct where description like 'diamond'`

Comment: @Balanivash: i  tried it too , but is not working :(

Comment: @Romi : is this the full query you are running?? cos both the above queries work perfectly for me.

Comment: This kind of error is usually backticks (`)  instead of single quotes ...

Comment: @ Balanivash: yeah this the full query, and  i am running it through SQuirrel SQL Client version 2.6.9

Comment: @cularis : I did not get your point, please elaborate

Comment: @Romi: I'm sure the query above is different than the one that you might be running. There is nothing wrong with the above query. But as your error message says, it is reading "diamond" as a column which can be if you are using back-ticks (`) instead of single-quotes (') around "diamond"

Comment: @Abhay: unfortunately I am very sure thatmy query is same as i have posted. And i am very sure with that i am using only single quote

Comment: @Abhay: See edit, i included description column values

Comment: @Romi: right, so what you need is to search the exact work "diamond" in description and the response by ratsbane is the perfect one. But I'm still not sure on the error that you had mentioned - "Unknown column 'diamond' in where clause"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to match "diamond" when it's a distinct word and not part of another word like "diamondville."  You could do something like SELECT * FROM tproduct WHERE description like '% diamond %' and this would match all of the records which have "diamond" surrounded by spaces.

But that wouldn't work.  That wouldn't find records where the description starts with "Diamond" or where there's a comma or period after "Diamond"

You need to match on a regular expression.  You can specify word boundaries with that:

```
select * from t2 where description regexp '[[:<:]]diamond[[:>:]]';
```

See this page for more info on MySQL regular expressions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression with a special pattern for word boundaries.

```
select description from tproduct 
where description regexp '[[:<:]]diamond[[:>:]]'
```

See [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
select description from tproduct where description like 'diamond'
```

Comment: @Romi,Can you give me the table structure please

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:
[Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698618/sql-latin1-general-cp1-cs-as-vs-latin1-general-cs-as)
    SELECT description FROM tproduct WHERE description ='diamond' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Comment: Why does appending `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` help? Isn't it only the sort order?

Comment: More generally, can you explain what it does and how it works (by editing your answer, not answering in comments)?

Answer (score -2):

```
select description from tproduct where description = 'diamond'
```