# SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS vs Latin1_General_CS_AS

Tags: sql-server, collation

What are the exact differences between the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` and `Latin1_General_CS_AS` collations in SQL Server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296936/) provides details on these collations and how they relate:

The only real difference is the sort order for some characters differs between the two collations. Character representation does not appear to differ.

The only thing I would add is that **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS** is the default collation for the *English (United States)* locale, and **Latin1_General_CS_AS** is the default collation for any other English locale, such as *English (United Kingdom)*.